# Jquery Validation, Show Custom message with value from id

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I Use jquery.validate.js for field validation.
Its display error messages as per declare in .js file for appropriate field.

I use this code for custom validation for email field.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#formcustomplan").validate({
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },          
            messages: {
                email: "Email is required in valid format"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Its display message like that "Email is required in valid format"
But I want that error message fetch email id and display it in error message.
(Ex. if I enter test.com in email box. it should display "test.com is not valid email" in error message)

### **Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUM8k/)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the default email validation message by using:

```
$.validator.messages.email = "Your custom message for email field"
```

In your case, you can prepend the new value from user's input to the custom message. Here is the trick using `keyup`:

```
$('.email').keyup(function () {
    $.validator.messages.email = $('.email').val() + ' is not valid email';
});

$("#formcustomplan").validate({
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUM8k/10/)**

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Validate actually supports [functions as messages](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) directly, so you don't have to do anything super hacky to make this work.  It is not well documented but you can do this:

```
messages: {
    email: {
        email: function (params, element) {
            return '"'+$(element).val()+'" is not a valid value';
        }
    }
}
```

Quote from the docs:

> Each message can be a String or a Callback. The callback is called in
>   the scope of the validator, with the rule’s parameters as the first
>   argument and the element as the second, and must return a String to
>   display as the message.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/XUM8k/11/